# How do I create a desktop shortcut for nnn file manager on Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: bash, mate-desktop, launcher

If I create an application launcher with the following command:

```
mate-terminal -e /usr/local/bin/nnn
```

a terminal opens and runs `nnn`. However, `nnn` doesn't have a configuration file and settings such as bookmarks are read from environment variables written in `~/.bashrc`. When the above launcher command is executed, `nnn` is not reading its variables from `.bashrc`, so no bookmarks. If I open a terminal and then type 'nnn' everything runs normally.

Comment: Does it work if you source bashrc? Try `mate-terminal -e ". ~/.bashrc; /usr/local/bin/nnn`.

Comment: Just tried: mate-terminal -e ". ~/bashrc; /user/local/bin/nnn" and the terminal opened and then closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [nnn Wiki](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki) section on Desktop integration.

To whoever deleted the earlier response: I have now linked to the project Wiki which I believe would be live as long as the project is. If the project isn't, the question becomes irrelevant.

I would like to link it instead of copying the current information here because the answer is not a one-liner and the specific project is the authentic source of the information and not stackexchange. The data can change and the commenters may not even be aware of it or remember to come back and edit their old comments.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I kept the exports in .bashrc and changed the Exec entry in ~/.local/share/application/nnn.desktop to: Exec=bash -ilc "nnn %f". Please note, it fails without the bash '-i' option. Also, I had to make a small adjustment to the icon path so that it was correctly displayed in the menu system.

Comment: Also, the Application launcher now works with the following command: "mate-terminal --title='nnn file manager' --hide-menubar --profile=nnn -e 'bash -ilc /usr/local/bin/nnn'"

Comment: Feel free to update the relevant program wiki (which is publicly editable) section if you have some new/interesting stuff to add.

Comment: The link is now dead. This is why you should copy/paste the answer.

Comment: No, it' not. The wiki is available.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki/Advanced-use-cases#desktop-integration), either:

1. Clone the repository, and run `make install-desktop`
2. Copy [nnn.desktop](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/blob/master/misc/desktop/nnn.desktop) to `~/.local/share/applications/`